# If Time Lords can recognise each other by mild telepathy, why do they fail to do so?

Tags: doctor-who

It was explained in [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/54532/how-do-time-lords-prove-to-others-that-they-are-the-same-person-as-their-past-re) Q&A that Time Lords can recognise each other even after regeneration as they are mildly telepathic.

If this is the case, why did The Doctor fail to recognise The Master until he revealed his identity in 'Spyfall'?

The previous Doctor also did not recognise Missy until she revealed her identity.

Comment: In the past, the Master's disguises worked perfectly fine more often than not. So the Doctor obviously doesn't use their mild telepathy on just anybody on the off chance that they might recognise someone.

Comment: Firstly, why do you assume that the Doctor uses telepathic check on everyone to determine if he/she is The Master or no? Secondly, The Doctor failed to recognize Master? Is there any proof that she used telepathy on C?

Comment: @Shreedhar I haven't assumed it - the previous Q&A I linked to discusses that Timelords should be able to instantly recognise each another, as this has been established in classic Who lore. Secondly 'C' was human. It was 'O' who was really the Master, and the Doctor did not recognise him or his TARDIS.

Comment: @Astralbee Classic Who lore usually has the Doctor not find out that the antagonist is the Master until at least the first cliffhanger! See https://www.blogtorwho.com/five-of-the-masters-best-disguises/

Comment: @MrLister Those are all *physical* disguises to conceal his outward appearance. Given that Timelords can change their physical appearance through regeneration anyway, such a disguise *alone* would be pointles and does not explain how he concealed being a Timelord, as per the discussion and accepted answer I linked to.

Comment: Perhaps a skilled Time Lord can consciously conceal his "psychic footprint" from others when he wants to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A: **The Master was using a *perception filter***.

When The Doctor questioned how The Master was successfully posing as a Nazi despite his appearance, he responded that he was using a *perception filter*. In previous adventures, The Master has used disguises to conceal his outward appearance, but on this occasion, he did not. Of course, given the telepathic abilities of Time Lords being discussed and their apparently ability to recognise one another, a physical disguise alone would not fool another Time Lord unless they employed something to block their inherent recognition as well.

The TARDIS also uses a perception filter - a telepathic device which misdirects the senses around itself or the person using it. In addition to the Chameleon Circuit (which is broken on The Doctor's TARDIS) this aids in hiding it by directing people to ignore it. This is why, despite being stuck as a British police box from the 1960s, most people do not question its presence.

Although it has been shown that certain people can see past perception filters when they already have an awareness of what is being hidden (for example, the Doctor and companions always recognise the TARDIS), the devices evidently do still work on Time Lords. For example, in *Castrovalva*, the fourth Doctor did not recognise that the fireplace was The Master's TARDIS until it dematerialised.

It is, therefore, possible that Missy (and other incarnations who used physical disguises) also used the same trick. When in the form of Professor Yana, his DNA had been rewritten by the Chameleon Arch, and so there was an entirely different reason The Doctor did not recognise him.

Comment: *For example, in Castrovalva, the fourth Doctor did not recognise that the fireplace was The Master's TARDIS until it dematerialised.* - and in the very episode you mention here - nor did the Doctor identify the house as a TARDIS despite having been in it...

Comment: @JonClements Indeed! The only reason I didn't mention this is because if this episode had contained a massive gaff, another mistake from the same episode wouldn't have proved anything. I am just trying to tie something established from classic Who to this story to show the continuity.

Comment: In Shada, the Doctor actually lands his TARDIS **inside another TARDIS** and doesn't notice